# How to add a columnar mariadb service in my gitlab-ci

Tags: mariadb, gitlab-ci, columnstore

I want to know how to add a columnar mariadb, 
I have already done for mariadb mysql

I shoul only change the name of service?

```
services:
  - mariadb/columnstore
```

or there are something else to add, and if i have a way to test